# Did the required reputation for leaving comments change recently?

Tags: discussion

I've previously left 4 comments on SO as indicated by my progress on the Commentator badge. However, now when trying to leave a comment on various posts, I always see that a reputation of 50 is required.

Could someone please explain what might be the cause?

I've made sure that these are not protected question and I've also tried searching on Meta for similar questions.

Answer (score 16):

> Could someone please explain what might be the cause?

You can always comment on your questions/answers and on answers to your questions.

To comment elsewhere requires 50 reputation - it is a [privilege](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment).

Comment: Thanks, that explains everything!